# Run an .exe file from C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\ect from different PC's

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows From application that runs several things on voice commands.

On a certain command I want to start Spotify, as you may know Spotify is installed in `C:\\Users\\Danny\\AppData\\Roaming\\Spotify\\Spotify.exe`.

This isn't a problem as long as my application is installed on my own PC. But when I want to run my app on different PC's this of course won't work.

Is there a way to maybe use a generic path to run this application?

Comment: [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Roaming means the contents roam to all machines you login into. That means, that Spotify can appear in different folders in the *same* machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Envoirment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If you use the Environment.SpecialFolder than it will get a path for the current user, so you don't have to type the path manually:

This example will get the path for the appdata folder. From there you can go further into the file structure, like I did with the Path.Comine() to prevent any path combine errors.

```
  // Get appdata folder path for every user
  string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
  // Your extension to Spotify.exe
  string extentionToPath = "Spotify\\Spotify.exe";
  // Finalpath, combine the appdata with your own extention.
  string finalPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, extentionToPath);

  // one line to get the path
 string finalPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "\\Roaming\\Spotify\\Spotify.exe");
```

So now as you can start the process by doing this:

```
Process.Start(finalPath);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. How do I use this in the following bit of code:

`case "hey eva, start spotify":`
                    `Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Danny\\AppData\\Roaming\\Spotify\\Spotify.exe");`
                    `break;`

Comment: You don't need to add `Roaming` because `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` points to the **roaming** data folder.

Comment: Thank you for saying that, I did not see that, I've made an update and now it is working.